# How complete is Obi-Wan's failure?

Tags: star-wars

In RotJ, When Luke fails to conceal Leia's identity, Darth Vader says "Obi-Wan was wise to hide her from me. Now his failure is complete." While the taunt is merely comical, I have a hard time disproving it, especially after the latest installment The Force Awakens.

> Consider that despite the separation, Luke and Leia are known to Vader, and the  outcome of all of this parading is essentially the Skywalker blood line being the source of Dark Sided torment and destruction for at least 3 generations, all of Obi-Wan's efforts to preserve the force in a good way end up with several planets being obliterated, countless murdered, and thus far the only remaining Jedi master to give up on his subjects (what exactly has the transcended Obi-Wan been doing the whole time Kylo Ren is wreaking havoc upon the galaxy) - Would it be safe to say that indeed his failure was complete, even as far back as RotJ?

I guess I'm speaking strictly from the movies. I don't know how much
has been written after the Force Awakens, so for all I know Obi-Wan's
efforts end up being more positive than negative. I just have a hard
time believing he is this wonder of the force when it seems his
closest companions are the central source of the evil in the galaxy.
Yeah, everyone can be swayed, but if you're so enlightened that you're
immortalized in ghost force form (Anakin and Yoda included) then how
do you just let the spiral of insanity happen? I mean, what else do
the ghosts of Obi-Wan, Yoda, and Anakin have to do besides train the
young Jedi right along side Luke? And wouldn't they have seen some
indication that Ben (Kylo Ren) was losing his grip on the force?

My vote is in. Obi-Wan's failure is complete. Do you have input to prove this incorrect?

Comment: I'm not clear exactly what kind of answer you're looking for here: You have several questions scattered in there, but I'm still not positive we have a precise definition of what you mean by "complete failure" on Obi-Wan's part that we could confirm/reject based on canon. If you can clarify that a bit, we can hopefully get this reopened for you.

Comment: What is it exactly you're after?

Comment: I guess I'm looking for ways his influence on other users of the force has actually benefitted the galaxy and whether or not his ghost form actually has any ability to surface at will instead of what seems to be sporadically. If indeed he is "more powerful" than vader can possibly imagine, how has that proved to be true if his disciples has all failed?

Comment: https://twitter.com/VeryLonelyLuke/status/689164676840730624

Comment: @KaiQing is your question answered by this previous one: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13875/did-obi-wan-kenobi-ever-become-more-powerful ? It's sort-of the same idea, though not exact...

Comment: I'm not sure that the obliteration of the planets and murder of countless people had anything to do with preserving the balance in the Force.  It wasn't done with the the Force, but with military technology - for evil yet pragmatic reasons that had to do with political power.